# AndroidのActionBarでtextColorPrimaryが効かない

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studioで、AndroidのActionBarの背景、文字の色を変更しようとしています。
ActionBarの背景　colorPrimaryで変更できましたが、文字をtextColorPrimaryでしていしても変更できません。
変更する方法を教えてください。

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
```

環境
Android　Studio　Ver4.2.1

Comment: themes.xml はどうなっていますか？

Answer (score 1):

英語版のほうには解答があります
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861661/actionbar-text-color

しかし、この内容でActionBarの文字が変更できない場合は、それがActionBarではなくToolbarの場合があります。
（Android Studioでテンプレートを使ってアプリを作った場合、ToolbarをActionBarのように扱う場合があります）
もし、Activity内で

```
    setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar)
```

のように初期化されている場合は、layout/app_bar_main.xml の内容を確認してください。androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar があるようであれば、app:titleTextColor でタイトルの色を変更できます。

```
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.MyApplication.PopupOverlay"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/red" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```